# Autofac, best practices on runtime adding tenants?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, autofac, multi-tenant

I am using the multitenant container and each tenant has its own database + connectionstring registered in a InstancePerLifeTime scope. The tenant is identified using a subdomain which is mapped in a "master database" with a generated database name.

Now I have two use cases:

Use Case A: Creating new Tenants:
Someone fills in a registration form with the companyname, submits, and after submission we generate a new database and that tenant should be able to access the application under companyname.domain.com

However we want to do that without restarting the application which impacts all current tenants.

Let's say I want to add a new tenant, runtime. What is the best way to register this without restarting the application?

At first I thought about registering the container, inject it in my MVC Controller, and add the new registration runtime but after reading some questions this appears to be bad practice.

I could also get the DependencyResolver from within the Controller and access the container from there. Are there better practices available?

Use Case B: Register on demand

Assuming we have a big amount of tenants and want to prevent registering them all at once on application startup. We could register these in the multitenantcontainer on the first request when the subdomain can be matched to an existing account.

This might be premature optimization though, since basically we don't have lots of tenants yet.

But again, this would result in runtime registrations.

Container:

```
        var tenantIdentificationStrategy= new TenantIdentificationStrategy();
        var multitenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(tenantIdentificationStrategy, builder.Build());
        var tenants = new[]
        {
            "companyA.domain",
            "localhost"
        };

        foreach (var id in tenants)
        {
            var databaseName = $"tenant-{id}";


            multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant(id, b =>
            {
                // Init RavenDB 
                b.Register(context => new RavenDocumentSessionFactory(databaseName))
                    .InstancePerTenant()
                    .AsSelf();

                // Session per request
                b.Register(context => context.Resolve<RavenDocumentSessionFactory>()
                    .FindOrCreate(context.Resolve<IDocumentStore>()))
                    .As<IDocumentSession>()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
                    .OnRelease(x =>
                    {
                        x.SaveChanges();
                        x.Dispose();
                    });

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to hold a static reference to the application container somewhere and register your tenants from there. This is pretty common practice and, since your tenant registration code is going to have to "know" what a `MultitenantContainer` is anyway, it's not going to change your assembly references or spread the "knowledge" of the container around more than it would otherwise have to be.

- Create the multitenant container at app startup.
- Register the tenants you already know about.
- Store the container in a static property somewhere that is globally accessible.
- Reference the static property when you need to register a tenant.

Comment: Hi Travis, based on some other questions around "how to make the container accesible from within the application" making the container available through a static reference appears to be bad practice. Would love to hear your thoughts about that.

Comment: If you're using it for service location (grab the container and directly resolve something) that's not good. This isn't that.